# Is the following attack on a DES-based commitment scheme valid?

Tags: encryption, block-cipher, des, commitments

I've encountered the following question while practising for an upcoming exam in Cryptography and would like to know if I'm on the right track:

> The following is a suggestion for a DES-based commitment scheme:
>
> To commit to $0$, choose a random $k$ and return
> $DES_k\big(\overline{0}\big)$ where $\overline{0}$ is a 64-bit block
> of zeros. To commit to $1$, choose a random $k$ and return
> $DES_k\big(\overline{1}\big)$ where $\overline{1}$ is a 64-bit block
> of 1s.
>
> Show how one can find $k',b'$ that are different to those chosen but which yield the same commitment, using at most $2^{35}$ encryptions.

I thought of using the birthday paradox to claim that if we test $~2^{28}$ keys on both $\overline{0}$ and $\overline{1}$ then we have a probability of $1/2$ to see a collision, under the assumption that the encryptions are similarly distributed for both.

I am not sure of this claim, but after having also considered how DES works internally, I cannot see any other way of solving this (I intitially also considered playing with the internal XOR function, but that got quite complicated and I was unable to complete this direction).

Is this correct? If not, would appreciate any help in understanding how to approach this.

Comment: "I thought of using the birthday paradox..."; as that would use fewer than $2^{35}$ encryption operations expected, why wouldn't that be a correct answer?

Comment: Is success with probability 1 required or not?

Comment: No, success probability 1 is not required - attackers are typically happy if their attack succeeds with good probability

Comment: ok I guess it's fair to assume that this is implicit

Comment: I think the $b$ must be $\overline{0}$ and $\overline{1}$ because only chosen values are the key and them So you need to choose $b'$ different from them. Now, the rest is the usual birthday-paradox...

Comment: @poncho 's last comment was what I was missing (wasn't sure that having 'good probability' was enough). Now I'm convinced it is the right answer. Thanks everyone!

Comment: Well, even %1 percent is too high for an attacker, as long as not negligible they will try to gain an advantage.